# Excel and javascript date calculations differ

Tags: javascript, excel, date, datejs

I am trying to do a date calculation in javascript that matches one in excel.

```
//Excel 
=(EDATE(DATE(2000,6,1),60)-DATE(2012,1,20))
```

This gives a result of -2424

So I try to do the same calculation in javascript with the following

```
//Javascript -  using datejs library
a = Date.parse('2000/06/01').addMonths(60);
b = Date.parse('2012/01/20');
a.setHours(12,0,0);
b.setHours(12,0,0);
span = new TimeSpan(a - b);
console.log(span.getDays());
```

This gives a result of -2423

I can't see why i am losing a day.
Can anyone shed light on how this could be happening.

Cheers for any help in advance. :)

Comment: Can you try printing out what is calculated by `EDATE()` and by `addMonths()` to see if they reference the same day?

Comment: The excel result is the correct one: from 2005-06-01, you need 30+31+31+30+31+30+31 to get to 2006-01-01, then 365*6+1(2008 leap year) to get to 2012-01-01, then 19 days to get to 2012-01-20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing else, two leapseconds occured in 2005 and 2008 (Both on Dec 31st), which either app could be taking into account. You've explicitly set your JS dates to "noon", but specified no times for Excel, so it's probably defaulting to midnight, which is when the leapseconds occur. That'd make your Excel date/times be 2 seconds off from the JS calcs, and could cross the midnight border, accounting for your one missing day.

Comment: I originally didn't have the noon settings but got the same result, so after reading some posts on here I added it to see if it would help but alas it did not.

Comment: I set the time of both dates in javascript to midnight and it seems to have resolved the problem. Thanks for your help.